# Rotating a div from the top left, transform-origin isn't working

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I am trying to simulate `n` amount of boxes rotating from the bottom-right position of the preposition div.

So, basically, I want the top left absolute position of `n`, be the same as the bottom right absolute position of `n - 1`. I really hope I explained this well enough, I just don't want there to be a gap, and want the boxes to rotate from the top left without moving to the  right or to the bottom.

I tried adding `transform-origin: 0 0;` but it still won't work.

I appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Here is the CSS:

```
.con {
  margin: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(140px, 140px) rotate(10deg);
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 138px;
  margin-top: 138px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(110px, 110px) rotate(10deg);
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 261px;
  margin-top: 261px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(80px, 80px) rotate(10deg);
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 354px;
  margin-top: 354px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(50px, 50px) rotate(10deg);
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 417px;
  margin-top: 417px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(10deg);
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div class='con'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like now:

[image: This is what it looks like now]

And here is the the [codepen](http://codepen.io/samirc/pen/oxxZQJ?editors=1100) where you can see the sandbox live.

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS or HAML->HTML compilation issue, **only post the compiled CSS/HTML**

Comment: Is that a rule? If so I will happily comply, but what if my 30 line Sass code compiles into over 1000 lines of CSS?  @cimmanon

Comment: Placing an [MCVE] into the question is the rule.  If HAML and Sass are not necessary to reproduce the problem, then they aren't part of an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are after.

View the link for the code to make sence.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bppRBx?editors=1111

```
.con {
      margin: 50px;
      width: 100px;
      clear: both;
      position: relative;
    }

.box:nth-child(5) {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 149.99962px;
  margin-top: 149.99962px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 289.01398px;
  margin-top: 247.33853px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 404.36784px;
  margin-top: 301.12891px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 486.32916px;
  margin-top: 323.09038px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
```

To calculate the start point of each new rectangle you need to use some trigonmetry to calculate the end position of the last one. Since this is not included in SASS/CSS you have to write your own functions. 
Daniel Perez Alvarez did a nice blog post on how to create simmplified versions of COS/SIN functions in SASS:
https://unindented.org/articles/trigonometry-in-sass/

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much good Sir. I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad to be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
use css attribute 'transform':

.your-class:hover {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.8s ease;
}
```

Comment: What.. this has nothing to do with what I asked? I didn't ask to use hover, I already used transform and I never said anything about animating anything with transition?

Comment: so, `transform: rotate(-45deg);` and so on may be help.

Comment: No it doesn't, thanks though.. Did you get what I was asking?